# The type 'Label' was not found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uno

I'm learning Uno/Xaml/Xamarin and doing some basic applications. In one StackPanel, I have a Label. When I try to compile, I get the following error:

> The type 'Label' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

I added the page through the normal right-click add, and selected blank page. This is the page's declaration:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Are Labels not supported in Uno? What am I missing here?

Comment: try cleaning your solution and restarting your IDE

Comment: I tried that to no avail. Now my MainPage.cs is saying "does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent'". That's just boilerplate code from the template. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: @shnar Maybe you can try to create new project to test again.

Comment: right click on your xaml page -> properties-> build action, change it to page and then reset it to embedded resource. This should work.

Comment: You should change your tag from uno to uno-platform so your question gets flagged by Uno team and community. Uno alone is unfortunately too generic.